# Save state of MediaPlayer on rotation

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am working on an app that has included an radio and everything is fine the play, stop, and pause buttons. My problem is that whenever a song is playing and I press the back button and reopen the app the buttons won't work with the current streaming radio

This happens as well when I change the orientation. Is there a way I can save the state of the media player and then obtain the state so that I can stop the song that is being played?

```
public class radioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button b1;
private Button Button1;
private Button Button2;
private String STREAM_URL = "http://192.99.35.93:6370/;stream.mp3";
private MediaPlayer mPlayer;
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_radio);
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonpredica1);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonpredica2);


    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    mPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    WifiManager.WifiLock wifiLock = ((WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE))
            .createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "mylock");

    wifiLock.acquire();
    wifiLock.release();

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                mPlayer.reset();
                mPlayer.setDataSource(STREAM_URL);
                mPlayer.prepareAsync();
                mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mPlayer) {

                        mPlayer.start();

                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because every time you either press back or rotate your device, your activity is destroyed and with it goes all of its state. If you want your app to keep playing under such circumstances (which makes total sense for a radio app), you'll need to implement the media playback logic in a service:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Regarding your need to deal with media playback in background, there is a very complete official documentation page on this topic:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

Answer (score -1):

Create a new object or class that is not GUI related that handles the radio.

in the constructor of your GUI add a parameter MediaPlayer that then sets the respective field to the Media Player.

Adjust the code of the buttons to interact with the Media Player Field. 
This will allow for you to open/close various windows that interact with the same MediaPlayer.

```
public radioactivity(MediaPlayer mPlayer) {
   this.mPlayer = mPlayer;
}
```

Comment: **Never** write a constructor for an Android Activity.